# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to access Flask Package from PyCharm

Tags: python

I am beginner, learning Python for about a month. I was trying to build a web framework in Python. I installed Flask as a package using `pip`, but when I tried to access it from `PyCharm`, it showed an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

I have included some screenshots.

This image shows the error I am getting:

[image]

This image shows I have Flask successfully installed in the system:

[image]

What could be the problem? And How do I solve it?

P.S: I am able to access the package from the command window. It's only when I am trying to access from `Pycharm`, the error occurs.

Comment: as far as I can tell from your screenshots, you have installed Flask globally on your system, but are running your project in a virtual environment. You need to activate the virtual environment before installing Flask (and any other packages you need for this project).

Comment: Are you used the same enviroment? maybe you are using different pythons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably started a new project using a virtual environment (venv), which is good practice. But then you installed flask globally into Python, which doesn't affect already created environments. Therefore, Flask is not available in your project's virtual environment.

As an extension to Robin Zegmond's comment: instead of installing your package through the command line, you can install it through PyCharm. This ensures that the packages you install are installed for the right interpreter/environment.

1. File > Settings > Project:  > Project Interpreter
2. Click the '+' sign on the right
3. Search for your module and install, this may take some time depending on the module.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error in **flask 1.1.*** with pycharm, after installing the lower version in the virtual environment, It is working fine.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with the help of Robin zegmond and Bram Vanroy's comments above. I was just starting out with python at the time of my asking this question and didn't know what a virtual and global environment was.

Comment: great @abrar-hossain, I recently find out the solution so I thought better to share, I got this issue because of flask version.